# How to Call JAVA GET request with JSON Array as a parameters

Tags: java, json, rest

Am trying to create a JAVA GET Http connection request with JSON Array data as shown below. where as the same code works with out any parameter (i.e. ?data={..})

```
String myurl = "https://myserver.com/test/api/v1/parameter?data={"username":{"name":"testusername"},"salary":{"sal":"56748","bonus":"3221"},"category":{"cat":"CATA"}}";
String newmyurl = myurl.replaceAll("\"","\\\"");
        log.info("**newmyurl*** "+newmyurl);
         URL url = new URL(newmyurl);            
         log.info("**URL*** "+url);
         HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();               
          // By default it is GET request
          con.setRequestMethod("GET");
          con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");              
          int responseCode = con.getResponseCode(); // Code breaks here nothing errors in log
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
      String output;
      StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();      
      while ((output = in.readLine()) != null) {
       sb.append(output);
      }
      in.close();

      //printing result from response
      log.info("****return string****"+sb.toString());
```

Comment: Your code is not valid Java.  Please post a [mcve] and explain what is not working.  Visit the [help] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To escape characters in a URL, use URLEncoder:

```
String myjson = "{\"username\":{\"name\":\"testusername\"},\"salary\":{\"sal\":\"56748\",\"bonus\":\"3221\"},\"category\":{\"cat\":\"CATA\"}}";
String myurl = "https://myserver.com/test/api/v1/parameter?data=" + URLEncoder.encode(myjson, "UTF-8");
```